# gVim - Omni completion preview window doesn't go away?

Tags: gvim, autocomplete

The omni-completion feature in gVim (under Windows, with mostly default settings) brings up a second buffer, called `[Scratch] [Preview]`.

When I finish selecting an item from the omni-completion popup menu, this buffer doesn't go away.  Currently, I am closing it via:

- <kbd>ESC</kbd>(to get to normal mode)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>k:q

I have seen questions on customizing the buffer height, or keeping it from popping up entirely, but I like the size, and I like having it there while I'm selecting.  Is there an easier way to get it to go away after I've selected what I want?

A simpler shortcut under Windows "default" bindings would be best, though careful remaps that aren't likely to interfere with anything would be okay too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to your vimrc to auto close the preview window when you exit the insert mode:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
```

Comment: +1; This is great :)  Out of curiosity, is there any other autocmd I could bind it to that would get it to close even sooner (yet not kill perf)?  If not, this is plenty good enough.

Comment: There probably is, but I don't know. Hopefully some superuser will answer your question.

Comment: Check accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105307/how-do-you-automatically-remove-the-preview-window-after-autocompletion-in-vim
Also @Profpatsch answer could work. (It did for me)