# Omnicompletion vim/gvim help window

Tags: vim, gvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [gVim - Omni completion preview window doesn't go away?](https://superuser.com/questions/305945/gvim-omni-completion-preview-window-doesnt-go-away)

Is there anyway to close the help window automatically when you close the drop down menu (triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>)?

Comment: I think you'll find an answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/305945/gvim-omni-completion-preview-window-doesnt-go-away